# How to change the biome, or at least the grass color, without mods in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As stated in the title, I need to change the biome, or at least the grass colour, without mods. I need a darker colour, so Forest would be the best I can think of.

So I searched in Arqade for existing questions about the same topic. What I found was **not** vanilla. The answers said that the only way to do this is with MCEdit, which I don't have. I don't have any mods, actually, which is why I'm asking for a vanilla way to do it.

Other answers were addressing the old 1.1/1.2 version of Minecraft, and I am using the latest version, 1.12.2.

So, any way to do it without mods? I know this search might as well be hopeless, but I might as well try.

Thanks to anyone who can find an answer!

Comment: Great! **So show us what you found**. Just saying you searched helps us nothing at all.

Comment: You're going to have to wait until 1.13 comes out at least before being able to do this in vanilla.  It's currently an unconfirmed feature for 1.13, meaning it's not even in the snapshots yet.

Comment: I should mention that MCEdit is not a mod or a part of the game at all. It's an external program that edits save data. In that regard it is literally restricted to vanilla; the edits it makes has to coincide with what vanilla expects. Now, if you're intending to manipulate biomes on-demand in-game (such as for a minigame where the biomes change periodically during gameplay), then MCEdit won't work since that would be a one-time operation outside the game (so you may need to clarify that particular intent).

Comment: What @Skylinerw said. Mcedit is an external Programm, Not a mod, that allows you to alter the world while it's turned off, including changing the biome.

Comment: Even if so adverse to MCEdit, it should be possible to edit the map files with other programs, like a [hex editor](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/) or potentially even notepad.  This requires knowledge of how the map files work, though

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to change biomes in Vanilla Minecraft. You could use external editors, but if you also don't want to use them, it's not possible.

Comment: According to someone else, there might be a possibility of a command coming into 1.13 that will allow it. I hope it does get put in, because that will make things a lot easier :)

Comment: Yes. But currently, this is the only correct answer. You can mark it as accepted now and when the command gets added, you can switch the mark over to a new answer telling you how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try and do the same as this person here - [Is there a Minecraft command for changing biomes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267281/is-there-a-minecraft-command-for-changing-biomes)
Which won't change the biome itself but replace its blocks which would change the biome. Other than that you can search on google for Biome finder, paste your seed and find its x, and z.

Best Regards.

Comment: They were asking to change the grass color to that of a specific biome's grass color. You cannot replicate grass color using blocks alone.

Comment: Technically, green wool kind of looks like grass, but I'm using that for the border of the area so that will **not** work